# Attach bash script to apache start

Tags: apache, bash

I have a bash script that I want to be executed before apache starts or restarts.

I want my bash script to be executed when apache starts during the bootup process and when I manually run "/etc/init.d/apache2 restart/start".

There is an init.d script "/etc/init.d/apache2" but I rather not touch that file.

Google is not very helpful :)

Comment: Honestly, changing "/etc/init.d/apache2" is exactly the approach I would take. Why do you not want to touch that file?

Comment: @Ben Lee: My reasoning is that an Apache update might overwrite that file.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way `/etc/init.d/apache2` is written, you can't hijack it by putting your script ahead of `apache2ctl` in the `PATH` and modifying or renaming `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl` would be more likely to get undone during an update. So that leaves you with a choice of modifying `/etc/init.d/apache2` or magic.

It may be that the magic comes in the form of creating a symlink to your script in the appropriate `/etc/rc?.d` directories with an appropriate prefix that would cause it to run before Apache. On my system, the name might be `S88scriptname`, for example. You can make these links individually for each runlevel and manage them manually or, on systems such as Debian and Ubuntu that support it, you can model your script after `/etc/init.d/skeleton` and set the options in the [LSB header](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) appropriately (particularly the `X-Start-Before` keyword, perhaps) and use [`update-rc.d`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=update-rc.d) to manage the `rc?.d` symlinks for you.